# Motorcycle exhaust can size

Tags: motorcycle, exhaust

How does the length of the exhaust 'can' affect the noise level and engine response of a motorcycle. A number of articles mention how the pipework diameter affects response but I can't find much on the length of the 'backbox' part? If i was offered a system in three different sizes, say 230mm, 300mm and 400mm with the same header arrangement what would be the general effect? I'd assume the smaller the box the louder the exhaust as there is less room for dampening? Are there general attributes particular designs impart in a simple 2-1 system, in particular which give a more restrained exhaust note?

Comment: I can't really find correlation between the size and the noise, and that shouldn't be the only thing to consider, think about how the new exhaust will affect the stability of the bike. In my Yamaha XJ6s, many says it affects the engine smoothness and somehow stability in a very negative way, not sure how though.

Comment: I'm ideally looking to replace an aftermarket part with something closer to, but better than, stock. So weight-wise I'd be hoping its returning to around spec, its just there are options on the specifics now so by-and-large engine smoothness and noise are the primary concerns.

Comment: As to "how does length etc" have a look here : https://www.acoustics.asn.au/conference_proceedings/AAS2005/papers/34.pdf